# Paypal SetExpressCheckout Soap

Tags: java, web-services, paypal

when i try to setExpressCheckout, i get ack = success but not token return.

the version of paypal api is 87.0
Here the wsdl link : https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl

here to command i use in axis2-1.6.1 to generate java code

```
-uri https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsd -p com.paypal.soap
```

here the link to the java code that generated using axis2 https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B97cB4uxjmztbGgxRER6VjBWcWc

here the code for SetExpressCheckout

```
    PaymentDetailsType paymentDetails = new PaymentDetailsType();
    BasicAmountType orderTotal = new BasicAmountType();
    orderTotal.setCurrencyID(CurrencyCodeType.USD);
    orderTotal.setString("10.00");
    paymentDetails.setOrderTotal(orderTotal);
    paymentDetails.setPaymentAction(PaymentActionCodeType.Sale);

    SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType requestDetailsType = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType();
    requestDetailsType.setCancelURL(buyer.getCancelUrl());
    requestDetailsType.setReturnURL(buyer.getReturnUrl());
    requestDetailsType.setPaymentDetails(new PaymentDetailsType[]{paymentDetails});

    SetExpressCheckoutRequestType requestType = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestType();
    requestType.setVersion("87.0");
    requestType.setSetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails(requestDetailsType);

    SetExpressCheckoutReq req = new SetExpressCheckoutReq();
    req.setSetExpressCheckoutRequest(requestType);

    RequesterCredentials requesterCredentials = new RequesterCredentials();
    CustomSecurityHeaderType customSecurityHeaderType = new CustomSecurityHeaderType();

    UserIdPasswordType userIdPasswordType = new UserIdPasswordType();
    userIdPasswordType.setUsername("<username>");
    userIdPasswordType.setPassword("<pass>");
    userIdPasswordType.setSignature("<signature>");
    customSecurityHeaderType.setCredentials(userIdPasswordType);
    requesterCredentials.setRequesterCredentials(customSecurityHeaderType);

    String endPoint = null;
    endPoint = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/";  //sandbox API Signature   
    PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceStub stub = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceStub(endPoint);
    stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, false);
    SetExpressCheckoutResponse setExpressCheckout = stub.setExpressCheckout(req, requesterCredentials);

    SetExpressCheckoutResponseType checkoutResponse = setExpressCheckout.getSetExpressCheckoutResponse();
    Calendar timestamp = checkoutResponse.getTimestamp();
    String strdate = null;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    if (timestamp != null) {
        strdate = sdf.format(timestamp.getTime());
    }
    System.out.println("Date:" + strdate);
    System.out.println("CorrelationID:" + checkoutResponse.getCorrelationID());
    System.out.println("ack :" + checkoutResponse.getAck());
    if (checkoutResponse.getErrors() != null && checkoutResponse.getErrors().length > 0) {
        PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceStub.ErrorType[] errors = checkoutResponse.getErrors();
        for (int i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(errors[i].getErrorCode());
            System.out.println(errors[i].getLongMessage());

        }
    }
    System.out.println("token:" + checkoutResponse.getToken());
```

here the result that i get

```
Date:17/04/2012 12:33:38
CorrelationID:a7c9fe7283bd
ack :Success
token:null
```

how i get ack success but token is null?
the contact person for paypal said that there is an EC token already be generated for CorrelationID:a7c9fe7283bd .

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

i have to use setExpressCheckoutResponse.getExtraElement().getText() to get the token. why setExpressCheckoutResponse.getToken() return null?

Answer (score 0):

If you look into mentioned wsdl file, at the beginning you'll notice the following:

```or-tag-here
<wsdl:definitions
     ns:version="89.0"
     xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
     ... >
```

Meaning that the version of API which should be used is `89.0` - don't remember where it's specified in PayPal API documentation, but this was mentioned there for sure.

Let me know if you still encounter this issue, since I've managed to set up PayPal Express Checkout using SOAP in Java recently and can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue and found the answer (this is for C#, I am not sure if it applies to Java):

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/soap/paypal-api-aa-and-net-wcf-undeserialized-fields

Look in the generated code for the web service (Reference.cs) and find the AbstractResponseType. The last property is Any(). Change the attribute to match this (to ignore the property):

```
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public System.Xml.XmlElement Any {
        get {
            return this.anyField;
        }
        set {
            this.anyField = value;
        }
    }
```

Following this, recompile and test again and you should now receive the Token property set correctly.

If you regenerate the web service code, this change will of course get replaced and you will have to re-do it unless PayPal fixes this. BTW, my WSDL Version number is 98.0 at this time.

Gary Davis