# Token Null in paypal expresscheckout

Tags: asp.net, soap, paypal

I am working with pay express checkout  in asp.net(3.5 or 4.0) with  website template.I have added its SOAP API reference from  below mentioned URL:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl. when I call setexpresscheckout method to get token value then it always return null as a token value and send token value in Any variable
which is useless for me.

if anyone can help me to get a token value in token property instead of Any property.Then Plz .......... do it fast

Comment: I found the answer and posted it over here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14713368/234004

Gary Davis